# How to make an interactive subshell in tcsh?

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, tcsh

How can I make an interactive subshell in tcsh?  E.g.:

```
% alias pathfrom 'cd `pathto -f`'
```

... where "pathto" is a script that asks the user (via STDOUT) for input (via STDIN) and prints a string in response.  Currently, "pathto -f" runs, but anything it prints doesn't show up in the terminal and the STDIN seems to be ignored.

My goal is to enable users to quickly share paths.  I have a simple script that let users on different machines on the same network using the same shared filesystem pass paths back and forth to each other, e.g. "pathto billj" sends my cwd to user billj.  The pathto script writes the cwd path to a specific file.  Then Bill J. can type "pathfrom", which is the alias above, which grabs the latest path.  I want "pathto -f" to ask the user which recent path to switch to, but it doesn't seem to be able to interact with the terminal.

Is there a way to have subshells talk to the terminal?  Or is there a better way to do this?